# How to convert database query with an in clause into a list of lists in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLAlchemy db query

```
test_query = Unit.query.filter(Unit.id_1.in_(('3D0U|1|A|G|1', '3D0U|1|A|C|160')))
```

I would like the result of this query to be a list of lists with **rows** corresponding to each **element** in the **in clause** as a **separate list**. Currently I'm getting all the rows in a single list

This is what I've tried

```
result = []
for row in test_query:
    result.append[(row.id_2)]
```

When I print out the results, this is what I get

```
["3D0X|1|A|C|160", "4ERJ|1|A|C|160", "4ERL|1|A|C|160", "3D0X|1|A|G|1", "4ERJ|1|A|G|1", "4ERL|1|A|G|1"]
```

The desired output is:

```
[["3D0X|1|A|C|160", "4ERJ|1|A|C|160", "4ERL|1|A|C|160"], ["3D0X|1|A|G|1", "4ERJ|1|A|G|1", "4ERL|1|A|G|1"]]
```

Sample data from the Unit table is shown below

```
"id_1","chain_1","pdb_id_1","id_2","chain_2","pdb_id_2"
"3D0U|1|A|G|1","A","3D0U","3D0X|1|A|G|1","A","3D0X"
"3D0U|1|A|G|1","A","3D0U","4ERJ|1|A|G|1","A","4ERJ"
"3D0U|1|A|G|1","A","3D0U","4ERL|1|A|G|1","A","4ERL"
"3D0U|1|A|C|160","A","3D0U","3D0X|1|A|C|160","A","3D0X"
"3D0U|1|A|C|160","A","3D0U","4ERJ|1|A|C|160","A","4ERJ"
"3D0U|1|A|C|160","A","3D0U","4ERL|1|A|C|160","A","4ERL"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Unless this feature has been added recently, SQLAlchemy can't do this for you and you'll need to post-process the return from SQLAlchemy yourself

Comment: Based on the sample data from unit table I would say it might be better to spend more time on designing the database if possible. For example, should there be model `Chain` (i.e. table `chain`) with attributes `id` and `name`, and then references to those entries (integer type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved in the following way: first order by `Unit.id_1` in the query, and then

```python
result = [[unit.id_2 for unit in units] for id_1, units in itertools.groupby(test_query, lambda x: x.id_1)]
```

In case of postgresql there is also `sqlalchemy.func.array_agg` that could be used to construct an array of `id_2` grouped by `id_1`.

For reference, [python documentation for itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) describes what `itertools.groupby` does.

Comment: Does this depend on the python version? Would it work with python 2.7?

Comment: Hakala Getting a TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: @TheEmperor I had written the arguments in the wrong order

Comment: When I tried this, I'm getting TypeError: <itertools._grouper object at ....> is not JSON serializable. Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: @TheEmperor I guess I should have written `result = [[unit.id_2 for unit in units] for id_1, units in itertools.groupby(test_query, lambda x: x.id_1)]`

Comment: This worked! Would you mind to explain this a bit before I accept it as the answer. Thanks!